# Create responsive Bootstrap navbar with two rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am trying to create a responsive Bootstrap 3 based navbar with two rows. However, I am having trouble with the structure of the HTML and the collapse functionality.

Below is a visual description of the desired result, and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction in terms of HTML/CSS (with as much default Bootstrap functionality as possible).

**Essentially the menu is desired to do the following:**

- On tablet/desktop devices, the first row is the logo and a menu of
  small secondary links (Link1-3). The second row is the main menu with
  main links (LinkA-E).
- On mobile, the classic collapse design should
  appear with the logo and hamburger icon. The expanded menu should
  show the main links (LinkA-E) first, and then the secondary links
  (Link1-3) last.

**Tablet/Desktop device:**

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|  LOGO/BRAND                         Link1  Link2  Link3  |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|  LinkA  LinkB  LinkC  LindD  LinkE                       |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

**Mobile device (collapsed):**

```
|--------------------------------------|
|  LOGO/BRAND               HAMBURGER  |
|--------------------------------------|
```

**Mobile device (expanded):**

```
|--------------------------------------|
|  LOGO/BRAND               HAMBURGER  |
|--------------------------------------|
|  LinkA                               |
|  LinkB                               |
|  LinkC                               |
|  LinkD                               |
|  LinkE                               |
|--------------------------------------|
|  Link1                               |
|  Link2                               |
|  Link3                               |
|--------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If i had an html/css of your project i use it to show how you should do that, but in this context **THIS HTML** came from [static navbar example of Bootstrap v3.3.7](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)

actualy the idea is placing `<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">` in row below `<div class="navbar-header">` with floating and width it 100% of its space, then pulling up `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">` with `margin-top: -50px;`

With that media query we would sure it behave right in moblie device.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo/Brand</a>
  </div>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">LinkA</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LinkB</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LinkC</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LinkD</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LinkE</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-collapse {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-right {
        margin-top: -50px;
    }
}
```

**JUST** Let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works exactly as requested :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)