# Bootstrap double row in navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have changed the code of the standard `fixed nabar header` in BootStrap (no changes in CSS) to achieve to get the menu items below the logo like
[image]

But when using the code I am getting
[image]

Any suggestions?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
  
   <div class="row">
    <ul class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-nav ml-auto">
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="mailto:info@rotterdamsteelworks.nl"><small><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Stuur e-mail</small></a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="tel:00310184632456"><small><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i> +31(0)184-632456</small></a>
   </li>
    </ul>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo.png" width="400" alt="Rotterdam Steel Works"></a>
  
    <ul class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-nav ml-auto">
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="" href="certificering.php"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo_metaalunie.png" width="60" alt="Metaalunie"></a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="" href="certificering.php"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo_iso_9001.png" width="60" alt="ISO 9001"></a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="" href="certificering.php"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo_ce.png" width="60" alt="CE NEN EN1090"></a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="" href="certificering.php"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo_lr.png" width="60" alt="Lloyds overstempelbevoegd"></a>
   </li>
    </ul>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    </div>
 
    <div class="row">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">Over RSW</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="certificering.php">Certificering</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Media</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
   </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
 
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create responsive Bootstrap navbar with two rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301318/create-responsive-bootstrap-navbar-with-two-rows)

Comment: Almost Awais, now the menu is beliw the image but alligned to the right instead of centered.

Comment: Can you update the code please? or create a new question

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <ul class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="mailto:info@rotterdamsteelworks.nl"><small><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Stuur e-mail</small></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="tel:00310184632456"><small><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i> +31(0)184-632456</small></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo.png" width="400" alt="Rotterdam Steel Works"></a>

  <ul class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="" href="certificering.php"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo_metaalunie.png" width="60" alt="Metaalunie"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="" href="certificering.php"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo_iso_9001.png" width="60" alt="ISO 9001"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="" href="certificering.php"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo_ce.png" width="60" alt="CE NEN EN1090"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="" href="certificering.php"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/logo_lr.png" width="60" alt="Lloyds overstempelbevoegd"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">Over RSW</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="certificering.php">Certificering</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Media</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Change this code and say what happened pls...

Comment: The code seems identical except for `<ul class="navbar-nav mx`enter code here`-auto">`

Comment: i changed that,it was my fault. pls try again this

Comment: What did you change? I get the same result as before.